# Eclipse extracting executables at some unknown location

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have this plugin that when installed, extracts some executables at some temporary location, and uses them. Here is my code:

```
public class StartCheck  implements IStartup {

private BufferedReader buf=null;
public static String pathBandwidth;
public static String pathDeviceQuery;
public static String pathKernelLaunchOverhead;
public static String memoryLatency;

public void earlyStartup() {
    // This method checks for presence of nvcc when Eclipse starts-up.
    String command="nvcc --version";
    Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pr;

    try {
        pr = run.exec(command);
        pr.waitFor();
        buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        //print-out the nvcc version
        System.out.println(buf.readLine());
        Preparation.return_val=true;

        //extract the executables
        Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("PTXAnalysis");
        URL url_bandwidth = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("/Executables/bandWidth.out"), null);
        URL url_deviceQuery = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("/Executables/deviceQuery.out"), null);
        URL url_kernelLaunchOverhead = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("/Executables/empty"), null);
        URL url_memoryLatency = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("/Executables/memLatency.out"), null);
        try {
            url_bandwidth = FileLocator.toFileURL(url_bandwidth);
            url_deviceQuery = FileLocator.toFileURL(url_deviceQuery);
            url_kernelLaunchOverhead = FileLocator.toFileURL(url_kernelLaunchOverhead);
            url_memoryLatency = FileLocator.toFileURL(url_memoryLatency);               
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        pathBandwidth=url_bandwidth.toString();
        pathDeviceQuery=url_deviceQuery.toString();
        pathKernelLaunchOverhead=url_kernelLaunchOverhead.toString();
        memoryLatency=url_memoryLatency.toString();         
    }catch (IOException e) {
        //disable all commands since no further task can be done, prompt user to install nvcc.
        System.out.println("nvcc was not found on this computer. You won't be able to use the energy estimation plug-in");
        EnergyEstimator.return_val=false;
        Preparation.return_val=false;

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

When I install the plugin, it gives me this location (one of the many), where the executable has been extracted:

```
/home/limafoxtrottango/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.1_2069420271_linux_gtx_x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/460/0/.cp/Executables/bandWidth.out
```

Now, the problems: I can't find any such directory. I understand that it is a temporary directory, but it does not show-up even if Eclipse is running. I am using one of these paths to run an executable using ProcessBuilder. Here is the code:

```
public static void runExecutable(){
    initializeArray();
    path_result="/home/"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"/kernelLaunchOverhead.txt";
    String path_executable=StartCheck.pathKernelLaunchOverhead.substring(path_result.indexOf('/'),path_result.lastIndexOf('/')+1); //path to the directory in which the executable is extracted
    try {
        fw = new FileWriter(path_result);
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

            ProcessBuilder builder=new ProcessBuilder("./empty",Integer.toString(arr[i]));
            builder.directory(new File(path_executable));
            int av=0;
            float sum=0;

                while(av<10){
                    Process pr=builder.start();
                    stdin = pr.getInputStream();
                    isr = new InputStreamReader(stdin);
                    br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                    sum=sum+Float.parseFloat(line=br.readLine());
                    av++;
                }
                fw.write(arr[i]+"   "+Float.toString(sum/10));
                fw.write("\n");
            }
        fw.close();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    FillArrays(path_result);
    BestLineFit();
    saveModel("/home/"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"/KernelLaunchOverheadModel.txt");
}
```

On invoking this function, nothing happens. It does not even throw any **FileNotFound** exceptions. Normally, it should have found the executable in the directory, and run it. But after installing the plugin, nothing happens.

To re-iterate, the class **StartCheck** is successfully showing to me the path to which the executables have been extracted. But those paths do not exist anywhere on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directories starting with `.` (such as the `.eclipse` in the path you show) are hidden on Linux and macOS systems.

You can see them from the command line using `ls -a`

Comment: Damn it. Pressing ctrl+H brought-up the files. Wasted almost an hour on this.